# There are a standard EPUB version or format to assign with PGP?

Tags: integrity

There a standard way to assign (PGP) EPUB eBooks?

A way to use digital certificate, like in the [PDF's certificate-based signatures](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/certificate-based-signatures.html), but not PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could add a [signatures.xml](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-ocf.html#sec-container-metainf-signatures.xml) file to the epub. However, I don't know of any epub app that actually supports this feature.

I.e., you'd also have to provide readers with a standalone app that validates the checksums.

It'd probably be easier to generate an MD5 checksum for the whole epub.

Comment: Yes, even without concrete examples or benchmark-applications, this is a good clue. The cited W3C standard, [XML DSIG Core](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-PGPData)  offers PGP (!).

About MD5, in nowadays it is not valid for secure assign neither integrity, for [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) we must use "modern" SHA256, SHA3, etc.

Comment: The [updated spec 3.1](http://www.idpf.org/epub/31/spec/epub-ocf.html#sec-container-metainf-signatures.xml) says *"Each Signature in the signatures.xml file identifies by IRI the data to which the signature applies, using the [XML DSIG Core] Manifest element and its Reference sub-elements. Individual contained files might be signed separately or together"*

Comment: Update, ref. may 2019.  See the [**Spec v3.2**, section 3.5.2.6 - Digital Signatures File (signatures.xml)](https://www.w3.org/publishing/epub32/epub-ocf.html#sec-container-metainf-signatures.xml)